# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test between two distributions - R

Tags: r, distance, kolmogorov-smirnov

I've two distributions computed on the same grid (that is, for each point of the grid I know the value of each CDF at that point).

I want to check whether the two distributions are the same. I can't use the `ks.test` command in `R` because this command evaluates draws from two distributions, checking the distance between the two empirical distributions.

However, being the two distributions computed on the same grid of points, the null hypothesis will be never rejected. How can I do this in R?

Comment: You may want to consider submitting this question to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), the statistics equivalent of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Perhaps you can take large draws out of both CDFs, and use ks.test to compare if the two draws are taken from the same distribution?